# How to discharge timer capacitor quickly?

Tags: circuit-design, timer

I have a simple timer in my circuit and I can't think of any solution to discharge C1 quickly:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwWKOb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- How can I discharge C1 in milliseconds when power is disconnected from the circuit?

Comment: Use a discharging MOSFET.

Comment: @Andyaka Hi, how do I trigger that MOSFET?

Comment: Well I can't say that I follow your circuit that well so I don't know when it needs to be reset or what other circuits you have that can perform this function.

Comment: @Andyaka I edited the question, I want to discharge the capacitor when power is disconnected from the circuit. I know there was a circuit in that you charge a capacitor with negative voltage and when power is disconnected it reversed the polarity and triggered a MOSFET but I can't quite remember it...

Comment: You can use a relay and its NC contacts. When the relay's coil is not energised the NC contacts can short the cap, likewise when it's energised they go open so the cap can be charged as normal.

Comment: I would probably use a P channel JFET (such as the SMP5115 or 2N5115).

Comment: @RohatKılıç I don't have enough power for a relay coil.

Comment: @PeterSmith Expand a little with example please.

Comment: @ElectronSurf Consider a normally-closed solid-state relay, then. They don't need as much power as standard electromechanical relays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just connect a low leakage diode from the + terminal to the +ve supply.

The diode will be reverse biased in normal operation, but on power-off, the node will track the falling supply to within a diode drop.

Whether this is sufficient depends on what you are trying to achieve (which you don't say).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVTKs0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What if the supply gets floating when off? It'll discharge through R2+R3 which is still quite high.

Comment: @RohatKılıç It will not float (in my case), it's like when a device gets unplugged.

Comment: @ElectronSurf Your circuit is based on too many assumptions. `it's like when a device gets unplugged` Yes, we expect the output voltage drop to zero within some time when we unplug the source. But we don't know the power supply and its configuration because they are not given. What if the voltage source is a flyback regulator with a large output capacitor, and it's very lightly loaded, which is not unlikely? The rectifier diode will not allow the cap to discharge easily, so the tracking will get some time. The requirement is milliseconds, and your circuit doesn't guarantee this.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I really appreciate the input, if there was something in the circuit that could affect the question I'd definitely add it in. it's really just a simple circuit.